# Log4J2 -How to set referince to my new loggers

Tags: java, log4j2

I have this xml config file for log4j2 but the loggers don't work. If I set the referince for root logger as "Errors" of "Info" (my new appenders) when I run the program the logger works and writes the data to logger files but if I set thouse appenders to my new loggers ("Information" and "ErrorLog") the logger doesn't write any data to my log files.

Here is my configuration xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration>

  <Appenders>

    <Console name="Console">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="Info" fileName="logs/info.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>

        <File name="Errors" fileName="logs/errors.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>

  </Appenders>


  <Loggers>
      <Logger name="Information" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Info"/>
    </Logger>

        <Logger name="ErrorLog" level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Errors"/>
    </Logger>


    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>



</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I modified the Loggers section and I deleted those 2 Loggers.

```
    <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="Info" />
        <appender-ref ref="Errors" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
```